# How to use Ajax Get method to connect WCF service? DO I need to start cros?

Tags: c#, ajax, json, wcf

I met an issue on Ajax to connect WCF Service. we are using Get and Post method to get JSON results. All I used is the stand coding from WebSite and We try a lot solutions about how to resolve this issue, but, unlucky, Nothing helps. We always get an error on CROS issue.

So does any new solution for this issue? It break us 2 days already.

Any suggestions is good. 
Thanks for your taking time looking this post!

Rocky

Comment: Please place your code here what you tried...

Comment: I am trying Add headers, crossDomain =true, and JSONP and something else. I am sure there is no issue on my code because Iphone client can call my WCF successfully. Only ajax calling faild.

Comment: you can enable your service to support jsonp via ajax,in that way you can make a jsonp call as cross domain

Comment: How to enable? Any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be below blog will help you in access WCF service in cross domain

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/wcf/X8QN260412-Calling-Cross-Domain-WCF-Service-using-Jquery.html

Comment: Check. resoled. Just use one of the solution in that link